# ExtJS 4.0 Row Expander

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, nested

Are there any known issues with the ExtJS RowExpander plugin when running under ExtJS 4.0? I've been getting errors about createDelegate not being a function. Was this removed in Ext 4.0? Are there any better alternatives for doing nested grids in this library?

Answer (score 1):

The rowexpander wasn't working in 4.0.2 but They fixed it for 4.0.4+ though.

Answer (score 0):

Emily is right, check out this thread:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137418-RowExpander-doesn-t-work-on-ExtJs-4.0.2-(ext-all-debug.js)-but-worked-on-(ext-all.js)

for more details (it provides a workaround that you can use for 4.0.2).